# sg-links.stackoverflow.email uses an invalid security certificate

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, email

This is in regards to the emails sent for stack overflow jobs. e.g. I get emails such as:

[image: screenshot of email]

However, when I click on the link, it's blocked due to an invalid SSL certificate:

[image: screenshot invalid certificate]

Comment: Are you using HTTPS Everywhere?

Comment: @DeanWard yes, but that's beside the point. Stack Overflow has [shown a dedication for https for a variety of reasons](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/).

Comment: Absolutely, and we’ll look into addressing it, but... The email rendered http:// for those links because `sg-links.stackoverflow.email` is a CNAME to a SendGrid owned server. Those are automatic rewrites SendGrid makes for click metrics which we’re not sure we can change the certificate for. HTTPS Everywhere has incorrectly specified a blanket rule for `stackoverflow.email` which is causing the issue you’re seeing.

Comment: Whilst having this domain without a valid cert is definitely an issue because of the risk of malicious interception it’s not affecting a huge number of users *by default*. What you’re asking is not a bug, it’s more of a feature request. Re-tagging appropriately...

Comment: @DeanWard The number of affected users is irrelevant: I still call it a bug.