# OpenID login form hidden

Tags: support, login, firefox, browser-support

When I try to log in to any Stack Exchange site, the login form doesn't show the OpenID login fields anymore:

[image: Login form missing some login options]

When I deactivate `display: none` from secondary-unified.css in the browser's web developer console, the form is shown again and I can log in using my openID.

```
#add-login-page #show-more-options, #login-page #show-more-options, #signup-page #show-more-options {
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
    margin-left: -2px;
}
```

[image: Login form with reactivated OpenID fields]

I'm using Firefox 62 with uMatrix, which blocks the following site elements (when testing on Super User).

- https://sb.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js
- https://secure.quantserve.com/quant.js
- https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js

Comment: It's probably related to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370220/suspicious-email-about-the-end-of-openid-support)

Comment: [OpenID is no longer supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307647/369403). This is by design, you can't log in using OpenID anymore.

Comment: How could I have missed that. Very unfortunate, though.

Comment: @yivi Because the answers to both questions are the same also means that one question is a duplicate, even though it is not about E-Mails but login forms? Additionally, I saw your linked question before, but the answers don't explicitly state the OpenID will be shut down, but the user OpenID provider won't be supported in the near future. However, if this question is a duplicate regarding to local standards, I won't object.

Comment: Yes @PVitt, I believe that since your question is answered there, it  is a legitimate duplicate. I think the accepted answer there makes clear that OpenID was going to be shut down. No other useful answer could be written here without refering to that one. Unless this one were about removing obsolete markup in the form, but that is not the case.

Comment: The SE announcment has been out for a while. There weren't much/any of the proposed notifications on the actual shutdown, nor was the date reliable. The login form must have gone sometime *this* week.

Comment: @yivi Sorry for not being exact, and just for the records: The answer in your linked question does not say that OpenID will be shut down. It says that the OP's OpenID provider will not be supported anymore. The OP's provider was Yahoo. In contrast, I host my own provider. But this is just my perspective.

Comment: @PVitt _"there is a legitimate email going out to **all users with OpenID credentials** attached to their account that will be expiring and will lock them out of their account."_ [emphasis mine] This, for me, is a clear answer that OpenID support was going to be shut down.

Comment: @mario To be honest, I don't remember any mail. But I also can't say for sure there was no mail. Perhaps I forgot about it. But the OpenID form is hidden for several weeks already. First I thought this is a bug, but as it wasn't fixed, I felt to ask about it.

Comment: @yivi _that will be expiring_, which doesn't mean that all OpenID credentials are expiring.

Comment: I guess I read it differently than you "All users with OpenID credentials that their credentials wll be expiring" === "all OpenID credentials will be expiring", for me.

Comment: The form was still there two weeks ago. There's been one announcemnt banner in July (only if you actually logged on), but definitely no mail (an OpenID account sort of implies that you've left no mail address). I kind of got the impression, great, SE team forgot about it.